# Azure Web Sites multiple instances using Http Runtime Cache

Tags: caching, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

Our plan is to migrate Azure Web Roles to Azure Web Sites. So far the Azure Web Roles were using Azure Caching that was shared across instances.

Our first thought was to switch to Redis Cache. But after a few other discussions we started discussing using just Http Runtime Cache as our data isn't big (we do not store any images or big data). It's all strings and numbers.

If go for Http Runtime Cache (using it on five instances of one Azure Web Site).

Could following scenario happen?:

1. Request comes to first instance that serves a content of freshly cached data.
2. User click's on an item but the request goes to second instance that has older cache at that moment that does not contain the item.

Would this result in an error? Is this a very possible situation? Can we be sure that the request will always go to that one instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Azure Websites implements sticky sessions, meaning that when a user makes a request and it gets routed to instance A, all future requests will also go to instance A for as long as instance A stays up